# Capture WiFi traffic from my own network

Tags: networking, vmware, wireshark, sniffing

As a self-study excercise I'm trying to capture traffic from my own network, so i set up a virtual machine with Kali and a TPLink WN722N usb wifi adapter attached (This is the only active interface on the vm). The host running VMware is connected through ethernet.

I connected the virtual machine to my own Wifi network, ran Wireshark, enabled the promiscuous mode for the interface in the capture options, and started to generate HTTP traffic from the host, but the only think im able to see in Wireshark is broadcast traffic from the host among other devices connected to the network (such as a TV and an iPad).

Also tried to put the interface in monitor mode with the following commands and running either Wireshark or tcpdump, but still no luck in capturing my own traffic:

```
 ifconfig wlan0 down
 iwconfig wlan0 mode monitor
 ifconfig wlan0 up
```

What am i missing here? What tests can i execute in order to find the issue and be able to capture the traffic generated by all the other devices?

Let me know if you need further explanation or any other details.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I personally use the packet wireless-tools to set up the monitor interface.

```
iw list
iw phy0 info
sudo iw phy phy0 interface add mon0 type monitor
sudo ifconfig mon0 up
ifconfig
sudo iw mon0 info
sudo iw dev mon0 set channel 1
```

Play with that. Use Wireshark on the interface mon0. When you finish delete the interface mon0

```
sudo ifconfig mon0 down
iw dev mon0 del
```